# Is it possible with Quassel to tell it not to join a channel at its startup

Tags: debian, irc, chat

Quassel has both a distributed core-client as well as monolithic core+client IRC client. I am using the monolithic one.

```
[$] aptitude search quasse                                                                                                        
i   quassel                                                         - distributed IRC client - monolithic core+client                           
p   quassel-client                                                  - distributed IRC client - client component                                 
p   quassel-client-kde4                                             - transitional package to quassel-client                                    
p   quassel-core                                                    - distributed IRC client - core component                                   
i   quassel-data                                                    - distributed IRC client - shared data
```

Now my question is, is there a way to tell `quassel` not to join a specific channel on a specific server while joining other channels (which is the default behaviour) of quassel. Is this possible, if yes, how?

My use-case is simple. While working I don't want any distractions, same is the case when not working.